# Convert 2 dimensional list into a string

Tags: python, string, list, nested-lists, string-concatenation

I have a 2 dimensional list which looks like this:

`[['OR', 'M', '0.0'], ['OR', 'M', '0.1'], [':=', 'M', '0.2']]`

I want to convert this list into an string. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a generator to flatten the list:

```
>>> l = [['OR', 'M', '0.0'], ['OR', 'M', '0.1'], [':=', 'M', '0.2']]
>>> ''.join(x for sl in l for x in sl)
'ORM0.0ORM0.1:=M0.2'
```

Comment: Why cant i assign the string to a variable?

Answer (score 2):

A solution showing of `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
m = [['OR', 'M', '0.0'], ['OR', 'M', '0.1'], [':=', 'M', '0.2']]
"".join(chain(*m))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.join` and `sum`:

```
>>> l = [['OR', 'M', '0.0'], ['OR', 'M', '0.1'], [':=', 'M', '0.2']]
>>> '.'.join(sum(l, []))
ORM00.ORM0.1:=M0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a string that use the character ',' between each item from the sub-lists and every sub-list will be warped separated with another symbol like '_' for instance. 
For example:

```
l = [['OR', 'M', '0.0'], ['OR', 'M', '0.1'], [':=', 'M', '0.2']]
l_string = ""
for sublist in l:
    for item in sublist:
        l_string += item + ","
    l_string += "_"

print(l_string) #"OR,M,0.0,_OR,M,0,1,_:=,M,0.2,_"
```

You can check in each for loop if this is the last round of the loop, and if it is, don't add the symbol ("," or "_").

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy array to get the result:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([['OR', 'M', '0.0'], ['OR', 'M', '0.1'], [':=', 'M', '0.2']])
arr = arr.flatten()
result = ''.join(i for i in arr)
print(result) #'ORM0.0ORM0.1:=M0.2'
```